Why slope of energy band is zero in non-depletion region of a biased PN Diode?
I know that slope of a energy-distance plot for carriers is -qE, where q is charge of the carrier and E is the electric field present. I've seen the energy band diagrams of PN diode in forward bias and reverse bias, where an external electric field Eext is responsible for biasing. The energy band plot shows the slope in the depletion region, that signifies the junction electric field Ej.

But in the non depletion region, the energy band shown is completely straight, with zero slope. My question is why the energy band have zero slope in this non depletion region, when there still exists the external electric field Eext which is present throughout the diode? Why the energy band diagram is not like this:


No, there won't be electric field far from the depletion region.

@naturallyInconsistent I'm not referring to the junction electric field's effect in non-depletion region, I'm referring to the external electric field Eext that is used for the biasing of the diode.

If you apply an external constant electric field, then you cannot incorporate it as a linear voltage slope over the infinitely large device. You'll have to find another way to extract the information you are seeking. There is already a fully-fledged and beautiful theory to get this.

@naturallyInconsistent I'm considering a case where pn junction is of limited dimensions (millimeters or lesser). Also in the texts it's mentioned that if we apply external constant electric field to a pure n-type or pure p-type semiconductor then it's energy band gives the slope as charge times that external constant electric field, then why it's not giving that slope in non-depletion region?

@naturallyInconsistent Also can you please share the link of any source (article or paper) that is having the theory to explain this, it will be a big help.

In a real device with current flowing there is resistance in the bulk regions, leading to voltage drops on either side of the junction in the bulk. Under normal device operating conditions these are small, but have to be accounted for in more detailed models of transistor performance.

@JonCuster please correct me if I'm  deviating from the concept, if the external electric field is constant, then using the formula that voltage drop equals integration of electric field w.r.t. distance, means significant voltage drop even in non-depletion region of diode, hence significant energy drop, so there should exist significant slope in energy band. Also I want to understand how resistance impacts energy level? as resistance is the quantitive measure of voltage required per unit current.
